# Github API Create Issues return 404 Not found

Tags: github-api

I am making a request to the below URL-
Post https://api.github.com/repos/kvimal/2048/issues
With my Token as a header for authorization.

The Curl Request

```
curl -i -X POST https://api.github.com/repos/kvimal/2048/issues  -d "{title:'hey'}" -H "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

And GitHub sends a response 404 Not found. I have reade the Documentation and as far as i have observed i am doing it by the github standards. Can anyone Help with this issues?

Comment: Please post your *code* for us to help with. If you are getting 404 errors, you are trying to access a URL that doesn't exist.

Comment: The above mentioned Url is the one i am trying to make a request to.

Comment: But the above URL *doesn't* return a 404. It works just fine. Your code obviously doesn't, so please share it.

Comment: sure i have edited my above post. With a curl request

Comment: And do you get a 404 with the `curl` request? How does this relate to Python at all now?

Comment: I have a backend code in python that parses the json url request i make to, which is in python. Sorry for the wrong tags

Comment: may not be actual answer but this may help someone.. in my case the issue was permission to the access token key created in git. I granted write package to key and it worked fine. Before that the error was 404 resource/file was not found at location.. (mostly due to security) (I wanted to add it as comment but not yet it seems)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As illustrated in this [python script](https://gist.github.com/spencerogden/4702275#file-gistcheck-py-L81-L84), the header should be using '`token`' not `Bearer`'

```
headers = {
  'Content-Type':'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'token %s' % token,
}
```

(That script doesn't use curl, but give an idea of the header)

For curl queries, see this [curl POST tutorial](https://gist.github.com/caspyin/2288960#post):

```
curl -H "Authorization: token OAUTH-TOKEN"
```

And the POST message must be complete as well (as in this [python script](https://gist.github.com/JeffPaine/3145490))

```
issue = {'title': title,
         'body': body,
         'assignee': assignee,
         'milestone': milestone,
         'labels': labels}
# Add the issue to our repository
r = session.post(url, json=issue)
```

(again, not curl, but gives you an example of the body)

Comment: Ah, indeed, see [this section in the documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/#basic-authentication); the API responds with 404 Not Found to not reveal private repositories.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I agree, but https://github.com/kvimal/2048 is a public repo, is it not?

Comment: A direct unauthenticated GET request certainly works, but for consistency the API may still use 404 to respond to invalidly authenticated requests.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that I understand, which is why I was pointing out the strange content of the header `Authorization: Bearer`.

Comment: Github is probably first trying to parse the `Authorization` header for the `token xxxx` form, and if that fails, falls back to expecting `Authorization: Basic`. If the latter fails then a 404 is returned.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I had to send the request , with form details in a json format.

Answer (score 10):

Go to "Edit personal access token" page, checkout the "Select scopes" session.

Make sure the token has been granted required access right.

I encountered similar case when trying to create public repo with 'Authorization: token ...' header.

Comment: This was issue for me. Shoutouts to GitHub for not adding any 'you lack permission' text in the response, sending us on this wild goose chase in the first place...

Comment: Thank you. It works after I add `public_repo` permission.

Answer (score 0):

I want to scream so bad right now!

If you leave an extra slash at the end of the graphql url then you will get a 404 error.

https://api.github.com/graphql is safe

https://api.github.com/graphql/ is a 404 error with no details.

I have spent the last 2 hours knowing my token or headers or query wasn't wrong and I was right! That little slash of hell will end you....