# Using GitHub API to create new issue

Tags: javascript, github-api, github-issues

I'm trying to create a GitHub issue using the GitHub API,
and I found this https://github.com/ceceliacreates/APITools which is exactly what I need, but it keeps showing me my GitHub API was not found.

Following is the code:

```
createIssuesFromJSON = function(file) {
    file.forEach(issue => {
        fetch(`https://api.github.com/repos/${user}/${repo}/issues/`, {
            method: 'POST',
            body:    JSON.stringify(issue),
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': `${process.env.TOKEN}`}
        })
        .then((res)=>{
            console.log(res);
            return res.json();
        })
        .then(json => {
            
        })
    })
}

createIssuesFromJSON(file);
```

error: 404 URL not found

I was checking the official GitHub website for the API usage, but I can't find anything wrong.
Can anyone help me with the situation?

```
[Symbol(Response internals)]: {
    url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/{my github}/{my repo}/issues/',
    status: 404,
    statusText: 'Not Found',
    headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] },
    counter: 0
  }
}
```

Comment: The original has [no slash at the end](https://github.com/ceceliacreates/APITools/blob/e645db5036cd1f76820e86be4ec2c17dde77def1/CreateIssuesFromJSON/CreateIssuesFromJSON.js#L9).

Answer (score 0):

That code is from [`github.com/ceceliacreates/APITools/CreateIssuesFromJSON/CreateIssuesFromJSON.js`](https://github.com/ceceliacreates/APITools/blob/e645db5036cd1f76820e86be4ec2c17dde77def1/CreateIssuesFromJSON/CreateIssuesFromJSON.js#L7-L19).
Except with `fetch("https://api.github.com/repos/${user}/${repo}/issues")`

It seems to follow the header [I mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28937149/6309).

You need to double-check the token used, and its [associated scope](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps#available-scopes).

And try to use the library itself.